# PostgreSQL prevents HDD from spin-down

Tags: postgresql, linux

I am using my router with OpenWRT as a small server. To experiment a little with more advanced database administration in my programming projects I set up psql on it. The.server uses my HDD, which is attached via USB to the router. This is no high-availability.system,. primarily as a DB connection point inside my private network.

Everything is going alright so far. I just experienced that my hd-idle setup is not working anymore. I highly suspect PostgreSQL to be the reason for that. Since the drive is not really that quiet and it's standing in my living room, I was Keen to spin the HDD down if I didn't use it for an hour. I now register quite some regular I/O on the device and I guess it's logging or similar processes. 
Is it possible to reduce the frequency of these helper processes down to maybe once a day?

Comment: SSDs are not that expensive these days; any reason you don't want to buy one?

Comment: Simply because I had the HDD already and wanted to use existing hardware!

Comment: Postgresql has also a totally braindamaged feature that it `sync()` disk on all write operations. You can turn it off somewhere in postgresql.conf . Also Ext4 fs has a braindamaged option that it syncs data in every 5 **seconds**, it can be turned off with mount flags. Well, and the linux VM has also a braindamaed feature that it uses a very small write cache, it can be turned off with sysctls. Doing all 3, postgresql will be *much* faster than mysql and probably no one can say why it is not the default.......

Comment: Hm. That might be an experiment. I can imagine that would tax the RAM of system a little bit more though...

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL, and with what settings?  Is the database completely idle?

Answer (score 1):

OpenWRT doesn't provide *anything* that I know of anyway to spindown hard drives. [From the documentation,](https://oldwiki.archive.openwrt.org/doc/howto/storage#automatic_spin_down_an_attached_hard_disk)

> Unfortunately there is no solution that works always for everybody. The first option to try is provided by the package [`hd-idle`](http://hd-idle.sourceforge.net/), which will spin down any disk accessible via the SCSI layer. Install it and test if it can spindown the hard disk (let us assume that your disk is /dev/sda):

The other solution is `hdparm -y`. So what you're doing is using something to tell your drives when to spin down. The idea is you now either

1. Script a daemon to monitor for when use stops (such as in the case of `unmount`),
2. Periodically tell the hard drive to spin itself down and hope it doesn't wake.

If PostgreSQL wakes the drive up, that's **absolutely** to be expected. Like any decent database, there is always maintenance to be done, and even when you're not accessing that database it will [`autovacuum`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-autovacuum.html). You may consider

1. Disabling `autovacuum` (which will help). But, then you'll have to manually [`VACUUM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-vacuum.html). Even disabling autovacuum, I have no idea if the PostgreSQL daemon will wake back up the drive.
2. Shutting down PostgreSQL before you set the hard drives to spindown.

Comment: Yes, I use hd-idle for the job. Since that works otherwise, I can consider that not to be the issue. This is also a question to try to understand the DB server itself better so it would be great if you could help me out there. What would I have to change to reduce (not deactivate) the I/O accesses? In what ways would that be a general penalty for my system?

Answer (score 0):

On an idle database server with default configuration, the only thing which would keep the hard-drive active is the "pg_stat_tmp" directory.  You can use the setting "stats_temp_directory" to move this someplace else, like a RAM drive (e.g. /dev/shm)